# Bounded function from [0,1] to $ \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am going through a particular proposition in analysis which says any function from [0,1] to $\mathbb R$ is bounded. The proof proceeds by proving that [0,1] is compact. Thats fine. But here is a function which I believe is unbounded.

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$. Clearly when $x=1$ the function goes to infinity and hence unbounded.

So how come compactness ensures boundedness for the above example?

Comment: The example you gave is broken because the function is not defined at the point 1. If you look at, for example, Rudin's Real Analysis book, you'll find out that the image of a compact set under a continuous function is also compact (bounded in particular).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is obviously false. The correct statement is that any **continuous** function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Your function is not continuous at $x=1$, it is not even defined there. (and doesn't matter how you define it at $x=1$, you will not get a continuous function here)

Comment: Thise is not correct. The function defined by the OP is *undifined* at $1$, and therefore it makes no sense to assert that it is discontinuous there.

Comment: If it is not defined at a point then it can't be continuous there. But maybe I should have written it in a more formal way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being formal. If $a\notin D_f$, then $f$ is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $a$.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, what I mean is that you can't even turn it into a continuous function by defining it at $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

Your $f$ is not defined at $x=1$. However, you can repair that by letting
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{x-1}&x\ne1\\42&x=1\end{cases} $$
This $f$ is unbounded, but has a discontinuity. And indeed, the original claim is only valid for *continuous* functions.